# Extract value from array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array of data and I am trying to access the tracking number field.

Someting like:

$array->meta_data->TrackingNumber

After 3 hours I cannot find a way to access it.

Any help much appreciated.

```
    array (
      'id' => 448,
      'parent_id' => 0,
      'status' => 'completed',
      'currency' => 'GBP',
      'version' => '3.7.1',
      'prices_include_tax' => true,
      'meta_data' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'id' => 8041,
          'key' => 'is_vat_exempt',
          'value' => 'no',
        ),
        1 => 
        array (
          'id' => 8043,
          'key' => '_wpam_id',
          'value' => '4',
        ),
        2 => 
        array (
          'id' => 8046,
          'key' => '_woo_pp_txnData',
          'value' => 
          array (
            'refundable_txns' => 
            array (
              0 => 
              array (
                'txnID' => '1U998392V9620752U',
                'amount' => '5.95',
                'refunded_amount' => 0,
                'status' => 'Completed',
              ),
            ),
            'txn_type' => 'sale',
          ),
        ),
        3 => 
        array (
          'id' => 8056,
          'key' => 'Payer PayPal address',
          'value' => 'anthony@befive.co.uk',
        ),
        4 => 
        array (
          'id' => 8057,
          'key' => 'Payer first name',
          'value' => 'Anthony',
        ),
        5 => 
        array (
          'id' => 8058,
          'key' => 'Payer last name',
          'value' => 'Evans',
        ),
        6 => 
        array (
          'id' => 8059,
          'key' => 'Payment type',
          'value' => 'instant',
        ),
        7 => 
        array (
          'id' => 8060,
          'key' => '_paypal_status',
          'value' => 'completed',
        ),
        8 => 
        array (
          'id' => 8061,
          'key' => '_paypal_transaction_fee',
          'value' => '0.47',
        ),
        9 => 
        array (
          'id' => 8290,
          'key' => 'TrackingNumber',
          'value' => '10046182',
        ),
        10 => 
        array (
          'id' => 8291,
          'key' => 'CarrierName',
          'value' => 'SEABOURNE',
        ),
        11 => 
        array (
          'id' => 10349,
          'key' => '_alg_wc_custom_order_number',
          'value' => '6',
        ),
      ),
      'line_items' => 
      array (
        48 => 
        array (
        ),
      ),
      'tax_lines' => 
      array (
        50 => 
        array (
        ),
      ),
      'shipping_lines' => 
      array (
        49 => 
        array (
        ),
      ),
      'fee_lines' => 
      array (
      ),
      'coupon_lines' => 
      array (
        51 => 
        array (
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far ?

Comment: `$array['access']['like'][0]['this']` for array layers. You're using object notation.

Comment: You want to search using one of the methods described in the duplicate, e.g. `$col = array_search(array_column($array["meta_data"], "key"), "TrackingNumber"); echo $array["meta_data"][$col]["value"];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access your array with $array->value, but the correct syntax would be $array['value']

I would loop through the meta data and check each key to see if is equals "tracking number" then echo out or do whatever you want with the result!

```
<?php

$test =array (
  'id' => 448,
  'parent_id' => 0,
  'status' => 'completed',
  'currency' => 'GBP',
  'version' => '3.7.1',
  'prices_include_tax' => true,
  'meta_data' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'id' => 8041,
      'key' => 'is_vat_exempt',
      'value' => 'no',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'id' => 8043,
      'key' => '_wpam_id',
      'value' => '4',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'id' => 8046,
      'key' => '_woo_pp_txnData',
      'value' => 
      array (
        'refundable_txns' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'txnID' => '1U998392V9620752U',
            'amount' => '5.95',
            'refunded_amount' => 0,
            'status' => 'Completed',
          ),
        ),
        'txn_type' => 'sale',
      ),
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      'id' => 8056,
      'key' => 'Payer PayPal address',
      'value' => 'anthony@befive.co.uk',
    ),
    4 => 
    array (
      'id' => 8057,
      'key' => 'Payer first name',
      'value' => 'Anthony',
    ),
    5 => 
    array (
      'id' => 8058,
      'key' => 'Payer last name',
      'value' => 'Evans',
    ),
    6 => 
    array (
      'id' => 8059,
      'key' => 'Payment type',
      'value' => 'instant',
    ),
    7 => 
    array (
      'id' => 8060,
      'key' => '_paypal_status',
      'value' => 'completed',
    ),
    8 => 
    array (
      'id' => 8061,
      'key' => '_paypal_transaction_fee',
      'value' => '0.47',
    ),
    9 => 
    array (
      'id' => 8290,
      'key' => 'TrackingNumber',
      'value' => '10046182',
    ),
    10 => 
    array (
      'id' => 8291,
      'key' => 'CarrierName',
      'value' => 'SEABOURNE',
    ),
    11 => 
    array (
      'id' => 10349,
      'key' => '_alg_wc_custom_order_number',
      'value' => '6',
    ),
  ),
  'line_items' => 
  array (
    48 => 
    array (
    ),
  ),
  'tax_lines' => 
  array (
    50 => 
    array (
    ),
  ),
  'shipping_lines' => 
  array (
    49 => 
    array (
    ),
  ),
  'fee_lines' => 
  array (
  ),
  'coupon_lines' => 
  array (
    51 => 
    array (
    ),
  ),
);


foreach($test['meta_data'] as $data){
        if($data['key'] === "TrackingNumber"){
                echo "The tracking number is: " . $data['value'];
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That really helped and I now have it working.